# Jmeter ActriveMQ Test Plan: having multipe topic subscriber/publisher

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic, broker

For my master thesis I built a pub/sub with ActiveMQ and now need to evaluate the broker's performance with Jmeter. To do so, I need to simulate the use case I implemented. It contains multiple publishers and subscribers sending messages to several topics. By now, I do not see a possibility to define that in the JMS Sampler. I tried to simply separate the topics by "," but it does not function.

```
dynamicTopics/MyStaticTopic1, dynamicTopics/MyStaticTopic2
```

I read all information about JMS Test Plans, but none is discussion this aspect.
Is there a way to do it?

Best regards.

Comment: Since destination is a standard `Destination` object, i'd look how it can solve this problem, regardless of JMeter. For instance, it seems should support [wildcards](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html), or maybe use server-side solution, such as [virtual destination](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html)

Comment: thx for the hint with wildcards. This should work :)

Comment: Not sure if you can provide the multiple destination in JMSSampler. the best you can do, to use multiple thread group for multiple destination to pub / sub.

Comment: yeah the wildcards are also not really working for my use case so I guess I have to use different thread groups. Are diffrent topics actually relevant for a stress test? Or is the frequency and threads in total more relevant to evaluate the brokers perfromance?